# Recursively finding and updating objects in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects which has further levels of children which follow the same pattern as that of their parents. A hierarchical tree view. My requirement is to do a recursion but in addition to that do updation to the parent array.
Input Array:

```
[
  {
    category_id: "1",
    name: "Books",
    parent_category: null,
    children: [
      {
    category_id: "48",
    name: "Arts, Film & Photography",
    parent_category: "1",
    children: [
      {
        category_id: "69",
        name: "Architecture",
        parent_category: "48",
        children: [],
      },
    ],
      },
      {
    category_id: "20",
    name: "Action & Adventure",
    parent_category: "1",
    children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    category_id: "2",
    name: "Action & Adventure",
    parent_category: null,
    children: [],
  },
]
```

I need to find and update all nodes that do not have further children with another key 'disabled: false' and those objects which has subsequent children with key 'disabled: true'.

expected result:

```
[
  {
    category_id: "1",
    name: "Books",
    parent_category: null,
    disabled: true
    children: [
      {
    category_id: "48",
    name: "Arts, Film & Photography",
    parent_category: "1",
    disabled: true,
    children: [
      {
        category_id: "69",
        name: "Architecture",
        parent_category: "48",
        children: [],
        disabled: false,
      },
    ],
      },
      {
    category_id: "20",
    name: "Action & Adventure",
    parent_category: "1",
    children: [],
    disabled: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    category_id: "2",
    name: "Action & Adventure",
    parent_category: null,
    children: [],
    disabled: false,
  },
]
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Below is the code that I tried, The problem is I cant align with the depth of the array with my updated array.

```
let newArray = []
const recur = (array) => {
array.map(childObj => {
    
  /* console.log(childObj.category_id) */;
    if(childObj.children.length) {
      /* console.log('innerchild',childObj.category_id) */;
      recur(childObj.children)
    } else {
            childObj['disabled'] = false
    }
    newArray.push(childObj);
  })
}


recur(arr);
```

Comment: have you tried something? what does not work?

Comment: post your code that you tried

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for the responses. I updated my question with the snippet that I tried with, it is incomplete still, I  can't get my updated array to conform to the tree view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate the elements from the array and add a property, depending on the children length and iterate the children as well.

```js
const
    update = array => array.forEach(o => {
        o.disabled = !!o.children.length;
        update(o.children);
    }),
    data = [{ category_id: "1", name: "Books", parent_category: null, children: [{ category_id: "48", name: "Arts, Film & Photography", parent_category: "1", children: [{ category_id: "69", name: "Architecture", parent_category: "48", children: [] }] }, { category_id: "20", name: "Action & Adventure", parent_category: "1", children: [] }] }, { category_id: "2", name: "Action & Adventure", parent_category: null, children: [] }];

update(data);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you do not like to mutate the data, you could map new objects.

```js
const
    update = ({ children, ...o }) => ({
        ...o,
        disabled: !!children.length,
        children: children.map(update)
    }),
    data = [{ category_id: "1", name: "Books", parent_category: null, children: [{ category_id: "48", name: "Arts, Film & Photography", parent_category: "1", children: [{ category_id: "69", name: "Architecture", parent_category: "48", children: [] }] }, { category_id: "20", name: "Action & Adventure", parent_category: "1", children: [] }] }, { category_id: "2", name: "Action & Adventure", parent_category: null, children: [] }];

console.log(data.map(update));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```